# How do I compute this expectation of sum of product of random variables squared?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, variance, gaussian

If $h_{1}, h_{2}, \dots, h_{N}$ are zero mean i.i.d Gaussian random variables with variance $\sigma_{h}^{2}$, how do I calculate the value of

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(h_{1}h_{2} + h_{2}h_{3} + \dots, h_{N-1}h_{N} \right)^{2}\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ \mathbb{E}\Big[\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}h_ih_{i+1}\Big)^2\Big] = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \mathbb{E}\big[h_ih_{i+1}h_jh_{j+1} \big]$$
Assuming that the variables are independent, we have
$$ \mathbb{E}\big[h_ih_{i+1}h_jh_{j+1} \big] = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\mathbb{E}\big[h_i^2 \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_{i+1}^2 \big] = \sigma_h^4 & \text{for }j=i \\ \mathbb{E}\big[h_{i-1} \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_i^2 \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_{i+1} \big] = 0 & \text{for }j=i-1 \\ \mathbb{E}\big[h_{i} \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_{i+1}^2 \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_{i+2} \big] = 0 & \text{for }j=i+1 \\ \mathbb{E}\big[h_{i} \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_{i+1} \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_{j} \big]\mathbb{E}\big[h_{j+1} \big] = 0 & \text{else } \end{array}\right.$$
In the whole sum the only terms that give non-zero contributions are those with $j=i$, therefore
$$ \mathbb{E}\Big[\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}h_ih_{i+1}\Big)^2\Big] = (N-1)\sigma_h^4$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! Will the final value be the same if I have to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[|h_{1}^{*}h_{2} + h_{2}^{*}h_{3} + \dots, h_{N-1}^{*}h_{N}|^{2}\right]$ (assuming all random variables are complex)? Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Assuming that $\mathbb{E}[h_i^*h_i]=\sigma_h^2$, the result will be the same. The important part is the independence which allows to factorize the expectation values, which leads to the ellimination of all terms with $j\neq i$.